# Nutiteq - ViewLabel not refreshed after returning from another Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, nutiteq

I have developed a ViewLabel with a custom View for my Polygons and I can show pretty well but when I go to another Activity ( through startActivityForResult() ) and return to my Map Activity with a value to update a TextView of this custom view I get the ViewLabel as before. I tried to invalidate before and after I set the number of notes but unsuccessful.

**Can you tell me what I am making wrong?**

That's the aspect before and after going to the another Activity

[image]

And here the Aspect of the other Activity, as you can see, there are 4 Notes

[image]

I tried to set the Note's count to the corresponding TextView but it is not showing the properly value

The Log of my onActivityResult Code shows, I can properly pass the value but the View is never refreshed.

```
I/WmsMapActivity(13656): onActivityResult:: requestCode: 12

I/WmsMapActivity(13656): onActivityResult:: requestCode: 12 result_ok

I/WmsMapActivity(13656): onActivityResult:: dataReturnedIntent != null

I/WmsMapActivity(13656): onActivityResult:: dataReturnedIntent != null textnote_number: 4
```

And it's code

```
                         ...
                case Constants.REQUEST_NOTES :
                      Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult:: requestCode: "+Constants.REQUEST_NOTES);
                     if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                                    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult:: requestCode: "+Constants.REQUEST_NOTES+" result_ok");

                                    if (dataReturnedIntent != null) {
                                           Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult:: dataReturnedIntent != null");
                                        String textnote_number = dataReturnedIntent.getStringExtra(Constants.TEXTNOTES_NUMBER);
                                     Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult:: dataReturnedIntent != null textnote_number: "+textnote_number);

                                      //textNotesTV.invalidate();
                                       textnotesTV.setText(textnote_number);
                                       //textnotesTV.invalidate();
                                 } else {
                                            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult:: dataReturnedIntent == null");
                                }
                           } else {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult:: resultCode != RESULT_OK");
                           }                               
                    break;
                   ...
```

Here the way I create a Polygon with its corresponding Custom ViewLabel

```
    protected void createPolygon(String id, String fieldguid, String fieldname, String farmguid, String farmname,  
                            PolygonStyle polygonStyle, TextStyle textStyle, 
                            double[][] coordinates, String latitude, String longitude, 
                            int state, int color, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> processingHistory, 
                            int bioIndTreatment, String bioindcrop, String bioindboundary, String croptype,
                            boolean shown) {

    // ****************
    boolean bioIndBoundaryValue           = true, bioIndCropValue    = true; 
    boolean existingBioIndBoundary        = true, existingBioIndCrop = true;        


    ListView      history_list_view;

    noteParamList = new ArrayList<String>();
    noteParamList.add("unclicked");           //0
    noteParamList.add(fieldguid);             //1
    noteParamList.add(fieldname);             //2
    noteParamList.add(farmguid);              //3
    noteParamList.add(farmname);              //4
    noteParamList.add(latitude);              //5
    noteParamList.add(longitude);             //6
    noteParamList.add(String.valueOf(color)); //7 color = original_color

    Log.i(TAG, "CreatePolygon:note: "+noteParamList.toString());
    // We turn into vividsolutions Object, so they provide getArea Method
    //
    /** User Data **/ // guid

    //pol.setId(Long.parseLong(id));   

    //Log.i(TAG, "CreatePolygon fieldname: "+fieldname + " processingHistory: "+processingHistory);

    Projection projGeo                    = geomLayer.getProjection();
    Projection projText                   = textLayer.getProjection();

    ArrayList<MapPos> outerPoses          = new ArrayList<MapPos>();
    MapPos center                         = null;

    for(double[] coord:coordinates){
        outerPoses.add(projGeo.fromWgs84((float)coord[0],(float)coord[1]));
    }

    //Setting Popup Label if we click the area
    LayoutInflater inflater               = (LayoutInflater) this.getLayoutInflater();

    labelView                             = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_field_newer, null, false);
    labelView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


    // Title - Fieldname
    TextView titelTV                      = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.popup_fieldname);
    titelTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    titelTV.setText(fieldname);        

    // Croptype
    TextView croptypeTV                   = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.popup_croptype);
    croptypeTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    croptype                              =  ( (croptype != null && croptype.length()>0 ) ? "Croptype: "+croptype:"Croptype: No data");
    croptypeTV.setText(croptype);              

    //Farmname
    TextView farmTV                       = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.popup_farmname);
    farmTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    farmname                              = "Farm: "+farmname;
    farmTV.setText(farmname);        

    // Area
    TextView areaTV                       = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.popup_area);
    GeometricUtils geomUtils              = new GeometricUtils();
    double area                           = geomUtils.computeArea(coordinates); 

    // Ceiling 2 decimal places        
    BigDecimal bd                         = new BigDecimal(area);
    BigDecimal roundOff                   = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    area                                  = roundOff.doubleValue();
    String areaString                     = "Area(qm): "+String.valueOf(area);        

    areaTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    areaTV.setText(areaString);        


    // Table 
    ImageView cropIV                      = (ImageView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.row_crop_value);
    ImageView boundaryIV                  = (ImageView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.row_boundary_value);
    ImageView treatmentIV                 = (ImageView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.row_treatment_value);

    int resImgId = 0;


    // Bio Ind Treatment
    switch (state) {
        case 0 : case 1:
            resImgId = R.drawable.empty;
        break;
        case 2 :

            if ( bioIndTreatment >= 3 ) {
                resImgId     = R.drawable.red;

            } else if ( bioIndTreatment == 2){
                resImgId     = R.drawable.ambar;

            } else if ( bioIndTreatment == 1 ) {                
                resImgId     = R.drawable.green;

            } else if ( bioIndTreatment == 0 ) {
                resImgId     = R.drawable.empty;

            }

        break;
    }


    Log.i(TAG, "CreatePolygon: state: "+state+" fieldname: "+fieldname+" color: "+color +" resImgId: "+resImgId);

    Resources res                  = getResources();
    Bitmap bm                      = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resImgId);
    treatmentIV.setImageBitmap(bm);


    // Bio Ind Croptype
    int resBioIndCrop              = R.drawable.no_processed_long_32;

    if ( bioindcrop != null && bioindcrop.length()>0 ) {
        bioIndCropValue            = Boolean.parseBoolean(bioindcrop);

        if ( bioIndCropValue  ) {
            resBioIndCrop          = R.drawable.red;

        } else {
            resBioIndCrop          = R.drawable.green;

        }

         Log.i(TAG, "createPolygon:: fieldname: "+fieldname+", bioIndCropValue: "+bioIndCropValue+" resBioIndCrop: "+resBioIndCrop);
    } else {
        existingBioIndCrop         = false;
    }

    bm                             = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resBioIndCrop);
    cropIV.setImageBitmap(bm);      

    // Bio Ind Boundary
    int resBioIndBoundary          = R.drawable.no_processed_long_32;

    if ( bioindboundary != null && bioindboundary.length()>0 ) {
        bioIndBoundaryValue        = Boolean.parseBoolean(bioindboundary); 

        if ( bioIndBoundaryValue ) {
            resBioIndBoundary      = R.drawable.red;
        } else {
            resBioIndBoundary      = R.drawable.green;
        }       
         Log.i(TAG, "createPolygon:: fieldname: "+fieldname+", bioIndboundaryValue: "+bioIndBoundaryValue+" resBioIndBoundary: "+resBioIndBoundary);
    } else {
        existingBioIndBoundary     = false;
    }       

    bm                             = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resBioIndBoundary);
    boundaryIV.setImageBitmap(bm);    

    // #Notes
    HashMap<String, String> settings = session.getSettings();

    textnotesTV             = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.popup_textnotes_btn);      
    setCountNotes(settings, textnotesTV, Constants.TEXTNOTES_NUMBER);

    picturenotesTV          = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.popup_picturenotes_btn);
    setCountNotes(settings, picturenotesTV, Constants.PICNOTES_NUMBER);        

    audionotesTV            = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.popup_audionotes_btn);
    setCountNotes(settings, audionotesTV, Constants.AUDIONOTES_NUMBER);

    videonotesTV            = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.popup_videonotes_btn);
    setCountNotes(settings, videonotesTV, Constants.VIDEONOTES_NUMBER);

    RelativeLayout relLayoutFieldInfo     = (RelativeLayout)labelView.findViewById(R.id.relLayoutFieldInfo);  
    //relLayoutFieldInfo.setBackgroundColor(color);

    // Table Layout
    //TableLayout tableLayoutPopupField   = (TableLayout)labelView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutPopupField);



    LabelStyle labelStyle                 = LabelStyle.builder().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE).
    setEdgePadding((int) (12 * scale)).
    setLinePadding((int) (6 * scale)).
    setAlpha(0.85f). // half transparent, half opaque!!! 
    setTitleFont(Typeface.create("Arial", Typeface.BOLD),16 * scale).
    setTitleColor(Color.BLACK).
    setTitleAlign(Align.CENTER).
    build(); 


    ViewLabel fieldLabel                  = new ViewLabel(null, labelView, new Handler(), labelStyle );        

    // Making a resizable View

    RelativeLayout relLayout              = (RelativeLayout)labelView.findViewById(R.id.relLayoutFieldLabel); 
    relLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    relLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                      MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    relLayout.layout(0, 0, labelView.getMeasuredWidth(), labelView.getMeasuredHeight());             

    // Without holes!
    Object obj                            = null;

    Polygon pol                           = new Polygon(outerPoses, fieldLabel, polygonStyle, noteParamList);


    // By Default : all invisible, just if we select one or several will be shown
    pol.setVisible(shown);
    //

    // Attach to geomLayer
    geomLayer.add(pol);
    myPolygons.add(pol);

    //Log.i(TAG,"createPolygon:: #myPolygons: "+myPolygons.size());


    double[] _centroid                    = centroid(pol);
    center                                = projText.fromWgs84(_centroid[0], _centroid[1]);

    Text textObj                          = new Text(center, fieldname, textStyle, null);
    textObj.setVisible(false);
    myPolygonTexts.add(textObj);

    textLayer.add(textObj);                                     
}
```

And the Layout 'popup_field_newer'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutFieldInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayoutFieldInfoHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_fieldname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Fieldname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_croptype"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/popup_fieldname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_fieldname"
        android:text="Crop : Triticale"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_farmname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/popup_croptype"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_croptype"
        android:text="Farm: Musterfarm"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/popup_farmname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_farmname"
        android:text="Area(qm): 123.34"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="18dp" />        
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/popup_sat_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linLayoutFieldInfoHeader"
        android:src="@drawable/sat_picture_no_available" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutIndicatorsAndNotes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relLayoutFieldInfo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relLayoutFieldInfo"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_bioindicators"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bio_explanation"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="BioIndicators"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/popup_include_header_indicators"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/popup_bioindicators"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bio_explanation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_bioindicators"
        layout="@layout/header_indicators" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/popup_include_value_indicators"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/popup_include_header_indicators"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bio_explanation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_include_header_indicators"
        layout="@layout/value_indicators" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bio_explanation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_include_value_indicators"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/history_description_new" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_textnotes_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bio_explanation"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bio_explanation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bio_explanation"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Number of Text-Notes: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_picturenotes_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/popup_textnotes_btn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/popup_textnotes_btn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_textnotes_btn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Number of Picture-Notes: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_videonotes_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/popup_textnotes_btn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/popup_textnotes_btn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_picturenotes_btn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Number of Video-Notes: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_audionotes_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/popup_textnotes_btn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/popup_textnotes_btn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_videonotes_btn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Number of Audio-Notes: " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The topic is discussed in the nutiteq-dev list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nutiteq-dev/bTEb1ScZnbs/ivBTV4-3BgAJ

p.s. usually cross-posting only creates more confusion.